# The Meaning of "to fall into the same essence"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can I be told what is meant by this sentence in some other way?

***X falls into the same essence that is at the heart of Y.*** [(Source)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0AfMBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22maintains%20the%20same%20fundamental%20requirements%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22maintains%20the%20same%20fundamental%20requirements%22&f=false)

 
*( What is meant by "to fall into the same essence" and "the essence that's at the heart of something" )*

[[ **The paragraph which the sentence is located in the main text**: (it's technical though)

Physical protection of any facility maintains the same fundamental requirements: You perform a threat analysis of your site, then you design a system that involves equipment and procedures, and finally you test it for adaptation. The system itself typically has a number of elements that *fall into the same essence that is at the heart of protection: deter–detect–delay–respond*. ]]

Comment: Welcome to Ell. I think you can furthur improve your question by addin more context or providing a link to the source of the quoted sentence.

Comment: I agree that more context is needed. At the moment, it's very hard to tell what this sentence means and it looks like rather bad writing.

Comment: Your text is either from a non-native speaker or it's someone with limited language skills unsuccessfully trying to use a register he's not very familiar with. Almost certainly what he's *trying* to say is something along the lines of *There is a characteristic which is central to Y (i.e. - it's the **essence** of Y, **at the heart of** Y), and X has that same characteristic (i.e. - it **falls into the same category** as Y).*

Comment: (I found and added link to original source. It's just bad writing.)

Comment: You can paraphrase it so: *A fourfold strategy is at the heart of any system which is designed to protect: deter, detect, delay, and respond.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is saying there are four considerations at the heart of "protection" (in general)

> deter
>   detect
>   delay
>   respond

He goes on to say that the design and evaluation of a protection plan ("X") for a physical asset, e.g. a building or a castle, needs to take into account ("fall into") these four essential criteria ("the essence").